# Serious confusion regarding central concept of torque

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I have taken physics, statics, and dynamics, and I have no problem with applying the concept of torque to a problem. But, I just cannot grasp why a force a greater distance away from the axis of rotational should cause a greater angular acceleration. Obviously I know this is true from empirical observation, but I am unable to get to τ = Iα using F = ma.

Let's say there is a ball on a rigid, massless rod fixed at a point it can rotate about. Starting with F = ma, substitute in a = αr to get F = mαr or α = F/mr. I am taking r to be the distance at which the force is applied away from the fixed point on the rigid rod. It appears that if you increase r, α decreases. This isn't right. If r increases, torque increases, and so must angular acceleration. I am severely lost here.

Comment: I think that what you're forgetting is that to use $F=ma$, the force must be applied directly to the mass. So not only is the force a (perpendicular) distance $r$ from the rotation axis, but so is $m$. So the particle's acceleration is the same for a small $r$ or a large $r$, but, by simple geometry, the *angular* acceleration is less for the larger $r$.

Comment: The relation a = αr is incompatible with F = ma because there’s no mass where you’re applying the force and r = 0 where the mass sits. Instead, try a work–energy relation where the work you do at the end of the lever arm goes into increasing the rotational energy of the mass.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using, for instance, $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$, you have to specify the system you're applying it to:

- $\vec{a}=\alpha r\vec{e}_\theta$ is the acceleration of a single point of the rod, not of the rod itself.
- At least two forces are applied to the rod itself: $\vec{F}$ that you mention, but also the force that holds the other extremity in place. Otherwise the rod wouldn't rotate, it would just move in the direction of the force.

When you're applying a force on a rigid body, there's a chain of action/reaction forces than appear alongside the body to keep it rigid in spite of the force you're applying.

Everything is hidden in the proof of $\tau=I\alpha$. You can see in the proof that Newton law for all points of the system are used and combined.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might give you better intuition is that the definition of an angle is the ratio of 2 lengths:

$$\theta = \frac{s}{r}$$

With $s$ being the arc length traveled along a circle, and $r$ the distance from its center. If you push on a rod with an applied force $F$, the linear work done to move a point on that object a distance $s$ will be $W=F s$, and will remain constant for a given fixed force $F$ and a given distance $s$.  But the angle $\theta$ subtended by that distance is greater when $r$ is greater.

So, the angle that a fixed amount of force will rotate an object depends on the distance from the center of rotation the force is applied, simply because of how an angle is defined. Torque is a measure of the rotation angle that will result from a given force.